# query with two key get one object in parse using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using [parse](https://www.parse.com/) in my app and I want to satisfy the two query and return object without using `orQueryWithSubqueries`. Here my query to parse code:

```
func queryToParse(){
    var queryForBlood = PFQuery(className: "Donors")
    queryForBlood.whereKey("BloodGroup", equalTo: bloodGroupTextField.text)
    var queryForCity = PFQuery(className: "Donors")
    queryForCity.whereKey("City", equalTo: citySearchTextField.text)
    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([queryForCity,])
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.tableData = objects as NSArray
            println(self.tableData)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my code only satisfy any one of the key but i want both to satisfy the key value and return objects

Comment: Do you want the 'and' of the two keys - donors in the specified city with the specified blood group?  If so the simply call `whereKey` twice on the same query with the two different criteria

Comment: i try this but it returns nothing ...var query = PFQuery(className: "Donors")
        query.whereKey("BloodGroup", equalTo: bloodGroupTextField.text)
        query.whereKey("City", equalTo: citySearchTextField.text)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                self.tableData = objects as NSArray
                println(self.tableData)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else
            {
                println(error)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Please improve this question.  Present a sample of the data from the data browser that the query should find or not find.  Be clear in writing about what you want, which two keys and whether you want records that meet both or either condition.

Comment: Then perhaps you have no records that match both criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating two separate `PFQuery`, then you just have to create one. You only need to create several `PFQuery` when you want to make an `OR` query.

---

Your code should look something like this:

```
func queryToParse(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Donors").whereKey("BloodGroup", equalTo: bloodGroupTextField.text).whereKey("City", equalTo: citySearchTextField.text)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        ...
    }
}
```